# How to connect with paired Bluetooth device programmatic in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, device

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth paired device. These two devices are paired with each other. Now when I try to connect with paired device it stuck with the connecting mode dialog. Log shows that it successfully connect but does not dismiss the dialog.

Here is my code snippet.

Main.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

    Button mScan;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Scan);
        mScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View mView) 
            {
                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "DeviceHasNoSupport", 2000).show();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
                    {
                         Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                     } 
                     else 
                     {
                        ListPairedDevices();
                        Intent connectIntent = new Intent(Main.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }// onCreate

    public void onActivityResult(int mRequestCode, int mResultCode, Intent mDataIntent) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(mRequestCode, mResultCode, mDataIntent);

        switch (mRequestCode) 
        {
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
                if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                {
                    Bundle mExtra = mDataIntent.getExtras();
                    String mDeviceAddress = mExtra.getString("DeviceAddress");
                    Log.v(TAG, "Coming incoming address " + mDeviceAddress);
                    BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mDeviceAddress);
                    pairToDevice(mBluetoothDevice);
                    Log.v(TAG, "pairToDeviceCalled");
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                {
                    ListPairedDevices();
                    Intent connectIntent = new Intent(Main.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "BTNotEnabled", 2000).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ListPairedDevices() 
    {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) 
        {
            for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) 
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "PairedDevices: " + mDevice.getName() + " " + mDevice.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }

    private void pairToDevice(BluetoothDevice nBluetoothDevice) 
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "InsidepairToDeviceCalled");
        openSocket(nBluetoothDevice);
        Log.v(TAG, "LeavingpairToDeviceCalled");
    }

    private void openSocket(BluetoothDevice nBluetoothDevice) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "InsideOpenSockedCalled");
            final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            final ConnectRunnable connector = new ConnectRunnable(nBluetoothDevice, dialog);
            Log.v(TAG, "InsideOpenSockedConnecterCalled");
            ProgressDialog.show(this, "Connecting...", nBluetoothDevice.getName() + " : " + nBluetoothDevice.getAddress(),
                true, true,
                new OnCancelListener() 
            {
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) 
                        {
                            connector.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            new Thread(connector).start();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Could not open bluetooth socket", ex);
        }
    }

    private class ConnectRunnable implements Runnable 
    {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog;
        private final BluetoothSocket socket;

        public ConnectRunnable(BluetoothDevice device, ProgressDialog dialog) throws IOException 
        {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
            this.dialog = dialog;
        }

        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "InsideRunnableCalled");
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                socket.connect();
                Log.v(TAG, "InsideRunnableSocketConnectCalled");
            }
            catch (IOException connectException) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Could not connect to socket", connectException);
                closeSocket(socket);
                return;
            }
            Log.v(TAG, "Connected");
            dismissDialog(dialog);
            closeSocket(socket);
        }

        public void cancel() 
        {
            try 
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Canceled connection", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void dismissDialog(final Dialog dialog) 
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.v(TAG, "DialogClosed");
            }
        });
    }

    private void closeSocket(BluetoothSocket nOpenSocket) 
    {
        try 
        {
            nOpenSocket.close();
            Log.v(TAG, "SockectClosed");
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Could not close exisiting socket", ex);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int mKeyCode, KeyEvent mKeyEvent) 
    {
        if ((!(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
            && mKeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && mKeyEvent.getRepeatCount() == 0)) 
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(mKeyCode, mKeyEvent);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

DeviceListActivity.java

```
import java.util.Set;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.device_list);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

        ListView mPairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        mPairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        mPairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) 
        {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) 
            {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mDevice.getName() + "\n" + mDevice.getAddress());
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            String mNoDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mNoDevices);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) 
        {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> mAdapterView, View mView, int mPosition, long mLong) 
        {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            String mDeviceInfo = ((TextView) mView).getText().toString();
            String mDeviceAddress = mDeviceInfo.substring(mDeviceInfo.length() - 17);
            Log.v(TAG, "Device_Address " + mDeviceAddress);

            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putString("DeviceAddress", mDeviceAddress);
            Intent mBackIntent = new Intent();
            mBackIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mBackIntent);
            finish();
        }
    };

}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidvouge.bluetooth" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <activity android:name=".Main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DeviceListActivity"     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" />
</manifest>
```

device_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_paired_devices" android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#666" android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stackFromBottom="true" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

device_name.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp" android:padding="5dip" />
```

main.xml has only button.

Here is the logcat output.

```
06-16 13:46:08.640 19062 19062 E CachedBluetoothDevice: updating profiles for $ $ S A \/ A N $ $
06-16 13:46:08.640 19062 19062 V CachedBluetoothDevice: opp classbits != uuid
06-16 13:46:08.640 19062 19062 V CachedBluetoothDevice: Class: 5a0204
06-16 13:46:08.640 19062 19062 V CachedBluetoothDevice: UUID:
06-16 13:46:08.640 19062 19062 V CachedBluetoothDevice:   00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
06-16 13:46:08.667 19091 19091 V TAG     : PairedDevices: $ $ S A \/ A N $ $ 00:1D:3B:05:B4:D5
06-16 13:46:10.582 19091 19091 V TAG     : Device_Address 00:1D:3B:05:B4:D5
06-16 13:46:10.597 19091 19091 V TAG     : Coming incoming address 00:1D:3B:05:B4:D5
06-16 13:46:10.597 19091 19091 V TAG     : InsidepairToDeviceCalled
06-16 13:46:10.597 19091 19091 V TAG     : InsideOpenSockedCalled
06-16 13:46:10.718 19091 19091 V TAG     : InsideOpenSockedConnecterCalled
06-16 13:46:10.789 19091 19091 V TAG     : LeavingpairToDeviceCalled
06-16 13:46:10.789 19091 19091 V TAG     : pairToDeviceCalled
06-16 13:46:10.800 19091 19128 V TAG     : InsideRunnableCalled
06-16 13:46:13.730 19091 19128 V TAG     : InsideRunnableSocketConnectCalled
06-16 13:46:13.730 19091 19128 V TAG     : Connected
06-16 13:46:13.730 19091 19128 V TAG     : SockectClosed
06-16 13:46:13.734 19091 19091 V TAG     : DialogClosed
```

Where am going wrong? Anybody who has successfully configured Bluetooth with processing dialog, Please give me a hand.

Comment: I have modified your Main.java file and posted below. Have a look. This might help you....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please modify your Main.java file like below and please keep the rest files at it is.

Main.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements Runnable 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    Button mScan;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private ProgressDialog mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog;
    private BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Scan);
        mScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View mView) 
            {
                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Message1", 2000).show();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
                    {
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        ListPairedDevices();
                        Intent connectIntent = new Intent(Main.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mTune.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View mView) 
            {
                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Message2", 2000).show();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
                    {
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        ListPairedDevices();
                        Intent connectIntent = new Intent(Main.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }// onCreate

    public void onActivityResult(int mRequestCode, int mResultCode, Intent mDataIntent) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(mRequestCode, mResultCode, mDataIntent);

        switch (mRequestCode) 
        {
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
                if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                {
                    Bundle mExtra = mDataIntent.getExtras();
                    String mDeviceAddress = mExtra.getString("DeviceAddress");
                    Log.v(TAG, "Coming incoming address " + mDeviceAddress);
                    mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mDeviceAddress);
                    mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Connecting...", mBluetoothDevice.getName() + " : " + mBluetoothDevice.getAddress(), true, false);
                    Thread mBlutoothConnectThread = new Thread(this);
                    mBlutoothConnectThread.start();
                    //pairToDevice(mBluetoothDevice); This method is replaced by progress dialog with thread
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                {
                    ListPairedDevices();
                    Intent connectIntent = new Intent(Main.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Message", 2000).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ListPairedDevices() 
    {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) 
        {
            for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) 
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "PairedDevices: " + mDevice.getName() + " " + mDevice.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            mBluetoothSocket.connect();
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        catch (IOException eConnectException) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", eConnectException);
             closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
             return;
        }
    }

    private void closeSocket(BluetoothSocket nOpenSocket) 
    {
        try 
        {
            nOpenSocket.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "SocketClosed");
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotCloseSocket");
        }
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "DeviceConnected", 5000).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: does it ask for pin No of bluetooth printer to connect? I am using mBluetoothSocket.connect(); and device asking me for pin No even device is already paired.

Comment: @Hayaßusa No. Check code inside question asked by `AndroidVogue`, He has done kind of coding to pair device programmatically.

Comment: i tried above code but unfortunately file or image or even simple message cant be sent..any error in above code...??

Comment: @Umang First thing is that above code simply list all devices and connects using socket. It does not send any message or anything. You need to write that code yourself. Second thing is that I just solved progress dialog error.

Comment: What is this applicationUUID?