# How to pair and connect a device programmatically using bluetooth in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Well there are plenty of question already have been asked on StackOverflow about how to paired & connect a remote bluetooth device with android. I have tried all the of them, haven't find any proper link or documentation regarding pairing with remote device.

Also about I have tried connecting my laptop with android programmatically, but I was getting following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:395)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:209)
```

There are number of reference for connecting android device, one that I follow is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369585/how-to-connect-with-paired-bluetooth-device-programmatic-in-android). But it's not working in my case. I am trying to connect with my vaio laptop and I have Samsung Galaxy S android device.

If anybody knows how to pair as well as connect the device programmatically then please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your client will never discover the server if the server is not actually discoverable. Your server code's comment says "Make sure the device it discoverable," but listening on a socket does not mean the device is discoverable. You can make the server discoverable by calling:

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

This is all covered in detail in the Android dev guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

your application must has the following bluetooth permissions in manifeast file:

```
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
```

Comment: I am not making android chat client application, where both peer are Android. Here I am trying to connect with Laptop and Car's bluetooth, I think using A2dp, I have to connect with these devices. If anybody is having experience then please share..